# it it possible to use the same alogorithm in two different publication?

Tags: research-process, computer-science

Currently, I am conducting a social media analysis research and have implemented a training algorithm where it combines various features of set to show that specific classifier works better than others.

The question is, can I use this algorithm in further work? Is it possible to use the proposed algorithm in other research ideas (I am using it now at twitter dataset)-if I apply it to FB dataset will it be considered new contribution?

Comment: Yes, even more than two.

Comment: Actually, depends the topic. If you use virtually the _same_ algorithm in two datasets, and perform the same analysis, it might not seem very good. Did you think to combine the two works in one paper together?

Comment: @PsySp no . I am thinking to work at separate papers. Why it is not good to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, yes.

It would be expected that there is some novel aspect in the second article, but the novel aspect does not need to be the algorithm.

It can be a different type of data (e.g., "bla algorithm applied to detect liver tumors" and "bla algorithm applied to detect stroke"), or a substantially larger dataset (e.g., "preliminary results of bla on 9 patients" and "results of bla on 500 patients"), etc.